# How do I pick up a change in URL with php?

Tags: php, url, variables

I have a textbox in which a user can input a name and it is stored as the following variable:

```
$name
```

After which, I have some php code that will create a string based on the contents of the input.

```
$site = "www.example.com/" . $username;
```

As an example, let's say the name John is stored, the $site variable would be:

```
$site = "www.example.com/John";
```

If I were to go to that URL via my browser, I get redirected to:

```
www.example.com/73281
```

Essentially, a string of numbers for that name, and this string is unique to each name. How should I go about getting that new URL, all with php? After that I would proceed to extract that string of numbers, but the only part I'm unsure about is how to actually get that new URL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`

Comment: Are you using any MVC framework?

Comment: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`

Comment: @user2486495: I'm not too experienced with php, I am not too sure what that is and I would also prefer to keep it simple, but if there's absolutely no other option then I may have to use that.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Could you give me an example of how to use it based on my situation? Thanks.